# Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline doesn't exit while having a custom runner available and gitlab-ci.yml existing

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

Maybe I'm just tired or something, but I've registered a runner on an EC2 instance on AWS and my project has a gitlab-ci.yml like below. When I commit nothing happens - like there are no pipelines according to Gitlab. Did anyone experience anything like this ?

Example gitlab-ci.yml (looks exactly the same just different project name and dev branch).

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    environment: production
    # Pull docker image
    image: 'mjsarfatti/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php-aws:latest'
    # Setup AWS CLI to have proper credential keys
    before_script:
        - 'mkdir ~/.aws/'
        - 'touch ~/.aws/credentials'
        - 'printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/credentials'
    # Run deployment using EB CLI deploy on master branch
    script:
        - 'git checkout master'
        - 'eb deploy $AWS_EB_ENVIRONMENT'
    # Ensure to run deployment only on master branch
    only:
        - master
```

[Runner Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sowAH.png)

[Pipeline Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQUMN.png)

Comment: Maybe it's just a formatting issue (?) but at least in your code block above your YAML is not indented correctly.

Comment: I've tried to format it further using online yml formatters and it still didn't work unfortunately. Also if it was a formatting issue, shouldn't I at least get some error or at least a pipeline showing up?

Comment: Is your file named `.gitlab-ci.yml` (mind the preceding dot)? Also I just fixed the identation in your question to how it should look like.

Comment: yeah it is called that. Btw I figured it out and it's the dumbest possible thing. It's main by default, not master (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try again removing the `' '` around your commands in the script

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(
the thing is I have another gitlab-ci.yml for my second project and it's the same almost - including single quotes. It works as expected.

Comment: Are you committing your changes to the `master` branch ? The pipeline and the runner should pick up the job `only` committing to master

Comment: I figured it out and it's the dumbest possible thing. It's main by default, not master (facepalm)